# repeating code for each row jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, model-view-controller

Hope you can help me, which I think is really easy for you to solve :).

I have the following jquery script:

```
    $('#addpricebtn').click(function () {



    $('.stidinput').each(function (i) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Builder/rateretriever',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { id: $('.stidinput').val() },
            success: function (result) {
                $('.categoryinput').html(result[i].category + ' - ' + result[i].subcategory + ' - ' + result[i].site);
                $('.formatinput').html(result[i].format);
                $('.exclusiveinput').html(result[i].exclusive);
                $('.cminput').html(result[i].costmethod);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this script works, however only looks at the first filled in id and I would like to use the code for every row, that's why I have the code below... (I would like to use the same request with a different id on every line that's getting filled in by the user :))

```
$('#addpricebtn').click(function () {



    $('.stidinput').each(function (i) {

        var inputer = $('.stidinput').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Builder/rateretriever',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { id: inputer[i] },
            success: function (result) {
                $('.categoryinput').html(result[i].category + ' - ' + result[i].subcategory + ' - ' + result[i].site);
                $('.formatinput').html(result[i].format);
                $('.exclusiveinput').html(result[i].exclusive);
                $('.cminput').html(result[i].costmethod);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope you can help :).

**EDIT**

Sure, I have the following HTML Code:

```
<div class="io-container">
<table id="iolist">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Format:</th>
        <th>Exclusive:</th>
        <th>Start:</th>
        <th>End:</th>
        <th>Cost Method:</th>
        <th>Target 1:</th>
        <th>Target 2:</th>
        <th>Frequency Cap:</th>
        <th>RC Price:</th>
        <th>Impressions:</th>
        <th>Gross Budget Discount:</th>
        <th>Net Net Budget</th>
        <th>Net eCPM</th>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input class="stidinput" name="stidinput" type="text" /></td>
        <td class="categoryinput"></td>
        <td class="formatinput"></td>
        <td class="exclusiveinput"></td>
        <td>01/01/2015</td>
        <td>01/01/2015</td>
        <td class="cminput"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="rcinput"></td>
        <td class="impsinput"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<button id="addrowbtn">AddRow</button>
<button id="addpricebtn">AddPrice</button>
```

The user should be able to add a row and fill in the cell with class: *stidinput*, after that the user clicks the *addpricebtn* button which will retrieve the rates from the database in JSON format.  I need to find a way that the jquery script retrieves all the STID and fill's in the corresponding information received from the database and not only the first one...

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please edit your question and clearly explain the problem please?

Comment: `var inputer = this.value;` || `data: this.id,` ???  This is really not clear what you are asking...

Comment: I think inputer has to be defined as follow: `var inputer = $(this).val();` and data as well: `data: { id: inputer }`

Comment: @Banzay Yes that does work, but only for the first value. If I add another line, it's providing me with an error message... Error: Unable to get property 'category' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously your mistake is that you fill the 1st `TR` line within each iteration. I think you have first to catch a parent row of each `stidinput` and fill it with respective data. it may look like follow (And I think it don't need to use index):

```
$('#addpricebtn').click(function () {
    $('.stidinput').each(function (i) {

        var inputer = $(this).val();
        var currentRow = $(this).parent();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Builder/rateretriever',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { id: inputer },
            success: function (result) {
                currentRow.find('.categoryinput').html(result.category + ' - ' + result.subcategory + ' - ' + result.site);
                currentRow.find('.formatinput').html(result.format);
                currentRow.find('.exclusiveinput').html(result.exclusive);
                currentRow.find('.cminput').html(result.costmethod);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also you can add `if...` before ajax call to check is that row already filled to prevent both of repeated fill  of row  and excessive call of server script.

Comment: It didn't work exactly as I wanted. But you helped me figuring out the code and rethink it. Thanks!